# In the Yoneda Lemma, how is there an isomorphism $\text{Nat}[\text{Hom}(x,-), F(-)] \cong Fx$ when only $\text{Hom}(x,x)$ gets mapped to $Fx$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, yoneda-lemma

I've been trying to understand the Yoneda Lemma. I have done all of the diagram chasing and understand that the naturality is dependent on one element $id_x$ and all arrows all naturally extended from this point. But what I don't get is how there can be a bijection from $\text{Nat}[\text{Hom}(x,-), F(-)]$ to $Fx$. What does make sense at this point for me is that there can be a bijection between $\text{Hom}(x,x)$ and $Fx$. But when you look at $\text{Hom}(x,y)$, this would get mapped to $Fy$ and there would be no corresponding point in $\text{Hom}(x,x)$ so I cannot see how it can have a corresponding point in $Fx$...

The fact that the elements of $Fx$ is in one to one correspondence with all natural tranformations between the two functors is very amazing yet still mysterious to me. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you ever written out a concrete example?

Comment: The Yoneda definitely does *not* imply that $\mathsf{Hom}(x,x)$ is in bijection with $Fx$. Consider functors from the terminal category consisting of one object and only the identity arrow. In this case, $\mathsf{Hom}(x,x)$ is a singleton set, while $Fx$ can be any set whatsoever. Yoneda states that there is a (natural) bijection between the *set of natural transformations* $\mathsf{Hom}(x,-)$ to $F$ and the elements of $Fx$.

Comment: @Randall I have chased diagrams around using the $f: X  \rightarrow Y$ as the category and followed the diagrams around with $Hom(x,x)$, $Hom(x,f)$, $Hom(x,y)$ and $Fx, Ff, Fy$. Is there a illuminating example you can recommend?

Comment: @DerekElkins I was only saying that there can be (not must be) a bijection between $Hom(x,x)$ and $Fx$ and this is the only fact I can deduce so far since they are mapped to each other via natural transformation. What I cannot understand is how there can be a bijection between the set of natural transformations and the elements of Fx when certain natural transformations like $\alpha_y : Hom(x,y) \rightarrow Fy$ does not have a corresponding point in $Fx$

Comment: Have you written out the details for the case when $F$ is itself a Hom-functor, say $F(-) = \mathrm{Hom}(Y, -)$?  This should clarify most issues

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Doh I am getting confused left and right now. Then how would we compare the set of natural transformations with the elements of $Fx$?

Comment: @MichaelHong what do you mean by *compare*?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are confused by all the widgets at play in the *statement* of Yoneda's lemma. I will not prove anything, but I will state clearly what we are after.

First there is this functor $$y : \mathbf C \to [\mathbf C,\mathsf{Set}]^{\rm op}$$ that maps $x \in \mathbf C$ to the covariant presheaf $\hom_{\mathbf C}(x,-)$. Next if you take some $F$ in $[\mathbf C,\mathsf{Set}]$ there is this other functor $$\hom_{[\mathbf C,\mathbf{Set}]}({-},F) : [\mathbf C,\mathbf{Set}]^{\rm op} \to \mathsf{Set}$$
that maps any other covariant presheaf $G$ to the set of natural transformations between $G$ and $F$. We can now compose those two functors to get a functor
$$ \mathbf C \xrightarrow y [\mathbf C,\mathbf{Set}]^{\rm op} \xrightarrow{\hom_{[\mathbf C,\mathbf{Set}]}({-},F)} \mathsf{Set} $$
Let us call $\underline F$ this new functor. This is a functor $\mathbf C \to \mathsf{Set}$ so it makes sense to ask wether it is isomorphic to another functor of the same type, for example $F$. And the Yoneda lemma says presicely that:

> There is an isomorphisms $\underline F \simeq F$ in $[\mathbf C ,\mathsf{Set}]$.

---

Now the proof of Yoneda's lemma is quite enlightening so let me try to give you the means to understand it. The proof starts by defining a morphism $\underline F \to F$ and then proves it is an isomorphism. So how do we define such a morphism $\alpha : \underline F \to F$: it lives in $[\mathbf C,\mathsf{Set}]$ so we need to define it on every component $x\in\mathbf C$ and check that is is indeed natural. So we need a map $\alpha_x : \underline F(x) \to F(x)$ for each $x\in\mathbf C$. Start by detailing what is $\underline F(x)$: by definition it is $\hom_{[\mathbf C,\mathsf {Set}]}(y(x),F)$. So we need to define $\alpha_x$ that takes as input morphisms $y(x) \to F$ in $[\mathbf C,\mathsf{Set}]$ and renders as output an element of $F(x)$. Now detail a little what is such an input: a morphism $f:y(x) \to F$ in $[\mathbf C,\mathsf{Set}]$ the data for each $z\in\mathbf C$ of a map $f_z : y(x)(z) \to F(z)$ such that they verify the naturality condition, or by rewriting the domain of $f_z$ it is the data of maps $f_z : \hom_{\mathbf C}(x,z) \to F(z)$ for each $z$. Among all those $f_z$ that form the data of $f$, there is in particular $f_x:\hom_{\mathbf C}(x,x) \to F(x)$ that will become handy. Ok so now I am ready to propose some $\alpha$ to you: I propose the morphism $\alpha$ which is defined on every component $x\in\mathbf C$ by
$$ \begin{aligned}\alpha_x :\hskip 50pt \underline F(x) \hskip 10pt&\to \hskip 10pt F(x) \\ (f:y(x)\to F(x))&\mapsto f_x({\rm id}_x)\end{aligned}$$
I leave to you to prove it is natural. So we have defined a map $\alpha : \underline F \to F$. Now we have to prove it is a isomorphism in $[\mathbf C,\mathsf{Set}]$. If you think strongly about what it means for a minute ("there is a morphism $\beta$ in the other direction such that $\alpha\circ \beta$..."), you should understand that we need to prove that each of the $\alpha_x$ are bijective. I leave that to you again !

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was having problems with although you have gone into further detail which was also very enlightening. So missing piece that I was having trouble with was this: $id_x$ can be mapped to any of the elements of $Fx$ and this is the only degree of freedom in the natural transformation from $Hom(x,x)$ to $Fx$. So this fact paired with the fact that every natural transformation is determined solely by where $id_x$ is mapped to gives you a one to one correspondence between the hom set of natural transformations and the elements of $Fx$.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you want to see is that any $a\in F(X)$ determines a unique natural transformation. Define $\phi:\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)\to F$ to be the natural transformation whose component at $Y$, $\phi_Y$, is the function $f\in\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)\mapsto F(f)(a)\in F(Y)$. To see that this gives a natural transformation, take any $g:Y\to Z$ and see that $$\phi_Z\circ \mathrm{Hom}(X,g)(f)=\phi_Z(g\circ f)=F(g\circ f)(a)=F(g)(F(f)(a))=F(g)\circ\phi_Y(f).$$ In particular, notice our definition of $\phi$ implies that $\phi_X(id_X)=a$.

Now let $\psi$ be any other natural transformation $\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)\to F$ with $\psi_X(id_X)=a$. What does $\psi_Y(f)$ do to a morphism $f:X\to Y$? Because the action of a Hom functor on morphisms is defined by composition, $f=\mathrm{Hom}(X,f)(id_X)$; and by naturality, $\psi_Y\circ\mathrm{Hom}(X,f)=F(f)\circ\psi_X$; so $$\psi_Y(f)=F(f)\circ\psi_X(id_X)=F(f)(a).$$ But this means that each $\psi_Y=\phi_Y$ for any $Y$, or that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are the same natural transformation. So a natural transformation $\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)\to F$ is uniquely determined by the image of $id_X$.

So for any $a\in F(X)$, let's denote by $\theta:F(X)\to[\mathrm{Hom}(X,-),F]$ the map taking $a$ to the natural transformation $\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)\to F$ that takes $id_X$ to $a$. We have just proved that the function $a\mapsto \theta(a)$ is injective; but obviously, every natural transformation sends $id_X$ to some member of $F(X)$, so it's also surjective.

Comment: Thanks. This also makes sense and answered my question although I now I realize my question was worded very poorly...